# Symfony Sonata Admin - Multiple Dashboards

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

is it possible to get multiple Admin Dashboards within one project?

Like:

```
/admin/ got all stuff my admin can do
/user/ got only user stuff
/mod/ part for my moderator
```

Actually i only have /admin/ with full administration dashboard.

I don't want to use Roles for this - i really wand to have another url for each section

Comment: I tried to do it in a previous project but you wasn't able to do it. After some try with easy-extends bundle, I encountered several security issues. I used roles and it works perfectly and it was very simple. But if you don't want to use it, I didn't find the answer.

Comment: @AlexandreT i'm using roles at the moment. Didnt find another solution neither. Thanks for your answer m8

Comment: You could perhaps use the [easy-extends bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/introduction.html). So you will be able do easy extends sonata admin bundle three times. First for admin, second for user, last for mod. But I don't know how to configure each bundle in services.yml